# Ajax with include in ejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, ejs

When i try to add include in my ejs file its working fine.
HTML
report.ejs

```
<tbody>                  
    <%- include('include/playersTable'); %>
</tbody>
```

Javascript

```
$.get('/reports.ejs', function (template) {
    // Compile the EJS template.
    reportTemplate = ejs.compile(template);
});
```

But when i call it with ajax it says
include use relative path requires the 'filename' option.

And when i try it with client site

Javascript

```
$.get('/reports.ejs', function (template) {
    // Compile the EJS template.
    reportTemplate = ejs.compile(template, {client: true});
});
```

it says

include is not a function
    at eval (eval at compile (ejs.js:525), :103:17)

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are experiancing this problem is that ejs cannot access the filesystem on client-side (javascript). So what is happening is this:

1. ajax gets the `reports.ejs`.
2. ejs starts compiling.
3. when ejs gets to an `include` tag, it looks for that file.
4. since it cannot access the filesystem, it cannot find the file.
5. ejs sends an error.

---

#### On the ejs website it says:

Most of EJS will work as expected; however, there are a few things to note:

Since you do not have access to the filesystem, `ejs.renderFile` won't work.
For the same reason, includes do not work unless you use an include callback. Here is an example:

```js
let str = "Hello <%= include('file', {person: 'John'}); %>",
      fn = ejs.compile(str, {client: true});

fn(data, null, function(path, d){ // include callback
  // path -> 'file'
  // d -> {person: 'John'}
  // Put your code here
  // Return the contents of file as a string
}); // returns rendered string
```

---

Another workaround I recommend would be to define an `ajax` route, like so:

```js
app.get('/ajax/:filename', (req, res) => {
  res.render(req.params['filename'], req.query);
  // This allows you to pass data in ajax like: `$.get("/ajax/reports?username=jhon&hello=world")`
});
```

This does the rendering server-side, which *can* access the filesystem.